# JQuery to GET the link with # only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

For some reason , my variable $startwith is only getting home.php instead of the links that startswith '#'.(eg.href = "#A')...
This is my JQuery Form

```
    <ul>
            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="authors.php">Authors</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="viewAuthor.php">View Author Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="books.php">Books</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="viewBookList.php">View Books</a>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a href="publishers.php">Publishers</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="publishers.php">View Publishers</a>
                    <a href="addPublisher.php">Add Publisher</a>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a href="genres.php">Genres</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="genres.php">View Genres</a>
                    <a href="addGenre.php">Add Genre</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="signout.php">Sign Out</a>
                <br>
        </ul>

        <br><br>
<script>
            $(function () {
                $("a[href^='#']").on('click', function () {

                    var sW = $('a').attr('href').replace("#", "");

                    $.get("getpublisher.php", {startsWith: sW})
                            .done(function (data) {
                                $('#listData').html(data);
                            });

                });
            });
        </script>
        <div align="center">
            <a href="#A">A | </a>
            <a href="#B">B | </a>
            <a href="#C">C | </a> 
            <a href="#D">D | </a>
            <a href="#E">E | </a> 
            <a href="#F">F | </a>
            <a href="#G">G | </a>
            <a href="#H">H | </a>
            <a href="#I">I | </a>
            <a href="#J">J | </a>
            <a href="#K">K | </a>
            <a href="#L">L | </a>
            <a href="#M">M | </a>
            <a href="#N">N | </a>
            <a href="#O">O | </a>
            <a href="#P">P | </a>
            <a href="#Q">Q | </a>
            <a href="#R">R | </a>
            <a href="#S">S | </a>
            <a href="#T">T | </a>
            <a href="#U">U | </a>
            <a href="#V">V | </a>
            <a href="#W">W | </a> 
            <a href="#X">X | </a> 
            <a href="#Y">Y | </a> 
            <a href="#Z">Z | </a>

        </div>

        <div id="listData"></div>
```

getpublisher.php
In this case when I echo $startWith , it shows me home.php and my query returns me with a 0..Any idea how to change?

```
$startsWith = $_GET['startsWith']; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `publisher` WHERE publisher_name LIKE '"+$startsWith+"%' ORDER BY publisher_name ASC";
$r = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($r);
//echo $sql ;

if ($rowcount > 0) {


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['publisher_name'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: This my query when i echo it out...
SELECT * FROM `publisher` WHERE publisher_name LIKE 'home.php%' ORDER BY publisher_name ASC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the click handler you need the href of the element that was clicked.

```
var sW = $('a').attr('href').replace("#", "");
```

This will get the href of the first `<a>` tag in the page

Change to

```
var sW = $(this).attr('href').replace("#", "");
```

Inside the event handler `this` is the element the event occurred on